# MYSQL Select Statement results must contain two strings

Tags: mysql, select

I want to select a title from a database that can contain any amount of words in any order so for example i want to select a title : MY ISLAND George Blonde.

and i want to be able to select this title by searching the words but in not particular order example George blonde MY as a search.

I am aware of the queries such as LIKE '%%' AND MATCH AGAINST, i was wondering if anyone had any better ways?

Thanks

James

Comment: did you look into full text indexing?

Comment: i am now using regex in my msq query i can get it to work when the words are in order but no when they are not do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT TITLE 
>   FROM   DATABASE_TABLE
>   WHERE TITLE REGEXP '^MY'

:  I meant you can use and dig into Regular expressions to do such kind of queries.

Comment: thanks it doesnt appear to bring back results when a search for george island any suggetsions ?

Comment: SELECT TITLE FROM DATABASE_TABLE WHERE TITLE REGEXP '[^MY./\s\w*/]'